# Eliminate elements from array if they have same attribute value

Tags: jquery, arrays

I obtain the elements for my the array like this:

```
var headerElements = document.getElementsByClassName("headerElement");
```

And I like to eliminate the elements of the array that have the same value for the attribute "title", something like this:

```
  $.each(headerElements, function(i, el){
    el.attr('title') is already in the array, remove the element from the array
});
```

But I am not sure how to do it. If someone has a suggestion, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over your elements and store the `title` attribute in an `Array`. If the `title` attribute is already stored, remove the element from the `Array` :

```js
var selected = $('.common');
console.log('The array contains '+selected.length+' elements before any modification.');

var titleList = [];
$('.common').each(function(){
  if(!titleList.includes($(this).attr('title'))) titleList.push($(this).attr('title'));
  else selected = selected.not($(this));
});

console.log('The final array contains '+selected.length+' elements.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="common" title="1"></div>
<div class="common" title="1"></div>
<div class="common" title="2"></div>
<div class="common" title="2"></div>
<div class="common" title="3"></div>
<div class="common" title="3"></div>
```